# Write to MS Access table, python win32com

Tags: python, ms-access, insert, win32com

I'm playing around with win32com.client for python to try to write/insert a row to a MS Access table. I've found an example of how to connect and query an Access table [here](https://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/139/256/). Basically, their code slightly modified for my own use is:

```
import win32com.client

connection = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
DSN = 'PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=c:\\testdb.mdb;'
connection.Open(DSN)
recordset = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
recordset.Open('SELECT * FROM Table1', connection, 1, 3)
fields_dict = {}
for x in range(recordset.Fields.Count):
    fields_dict[x] = recordset.Fields.Item(x).Name
    print fields_dict[x], recordset.Fields.Item(x).Value
```

So this tells me how to execute a select statement on the Access table. I'd like to be able to write rows and data to the table. When using win32com for MS Office products, I tend to dive into the [MSDN pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799.aspx) and try to interpret the VBA code for python code, but this one has me a bit handcuffed. Couple that with no examples found on the internet after lengthy searches has made me second guess whether or not this is possible? hopefully someone out there has played with this before and has a suggestion.

Comment: If you can execute a `SELECT` statement with win32com then you can execute an `INSERT` statement too, although specifying the parameters for an `ADODB.Command` object will be somewhat verbose. A more common approach is to use pyodbc (or perhaps pypyodbc) with the Access ODBC driver to do such straightforward CRUD operations, and save win32com for performing lower-level manipulations of the database using Access DAO, e.g., to make structural changes that Access DDL cannot handle.

Comment: Thanks Gord. I'd like to stick with win32com if I can. I had a look at pyodbc in my travels through my searches. It's where I will go next if this doesn't work out.

Comment: To piggyback @GordThompson's comment, MS Access is both a backend database and a GUI .exe application. When intending to run SQL statements like inserting rows consider db api connections (e.g., odbc) like you would with other RDMS: SQLite, SQL Server, MySQL, etc. When needing to adjust forms/reports/macros/modules, run Access app methods like `DoCmd.*`, or other application layers then use COM interface. Remember too VBA is an external component to Access.exe and COM-connects like you are with Python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to the question, using pyodbc (or pypyodbc) and the Access ODBC driver is a more common way of doing CRUD operations, but if you *really* want to use win32com and OLEDB then you could do an `UPDATE` like this:

```python
import win32com.client

# ADODB constants
adVarWChar = 202
adInteger = 3
adParamInput = 1

connection = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
DSN = (
    r'PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'
    r'DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb;'
    )
connection.Open(DSN)
cmd = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Command')
cmd.ActiveConnection = connection
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Donors SET LastName = ? WHERE ID = ?"
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adInteger, adParamInput))
cmd.Parameters(0).Value = "Thompson"
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = 10
cmd.Execute()
connection.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks Gord. I made a few modifications for my own use and got your script to work for me. I'm also looking a little closer at pyodbc. You've been a good help. Cheers.