# How to use Python SQL "UPDATE" statement to update an MS Access MySQL table field that requires selection from a drop-down menu?

Tags: python, mysql, ms-access, pyodbc

I have a column in a MySQL table that, in the MS Access interface, requires the user to select a value from a dropdown menu.

I found that (using the python SQL UPDATE statement) I could not insert arbitrary values into the field without getting the following error:

```
DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (-3030) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Then I tried copying an exact value from the dropdown menu in MS Access, saving it as a variable in python, then inserting that variable into the field, and I got the same error as above.

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
copied_exact_value_from_database_dropdown = "exact_copied_value"
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\path\name_of_my_db.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')
cursor.execute(
    "UPDATE table_name SET field_with_dropdown = ? WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?", copied_exact_value_from_database_dropdown, 5285, 18)
conn.commit()
```

What are my options?  Do I have to add values to the dropdown table manually?  Can I do that through python?  Is there a different data format I should be using to insert the value?  Is there some way to return the values of the dropdown to python and then pop them back into the table using the update statement?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61235451/1422451). Simply you cannot access any MSAccess.exe GUI objects like forms with dropdown using `pyodbc` (a backend database connection). Remember MS Access is both an Office application and a database.

Comment: So is there a solution using win32com instead?  Or is there no way to access dropdown menu selection fields from python?

Comment: Whatever you can do in Access VBA, you can do in `win32com`. But to do so, you need to know the [Access object library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access/object-model). Why not pass the drop down entry directly into Python and why not directly connect to MySQL? Note: Python has many GUI solutions for data entry and well-known databases.

Comment: For your error, pass parameters as a tuple or list and not scalar values separated by commas: `cursor.execute("UPDATE ....", (copied_exact_value_from_database_dropdown, 5285, 18))`